# What are some examples of bad data models with regards to partition keys?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'd love to hear some examples with different problems regarding the partition key design, to get an idea of what type of issues can occur, like hot spots or something else that can happen. These can be totally made up scenarios.

I just want to build up an intuition behind approaching data modeling by learning about what can go wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Two short examples:

Alphabetical order as partition key:
If you use alphabetical order as a partition key and your data is in multiple languages or writing systems, this can result in unequal distribution of data. 

Unpredictable or random values as partition keys:
If you use unpredictable or random values as partition keys, it can lead to uneven distribution of data. You will find that some partitions are overloaded while others are almost empty.

A good partition key should lead to an even distribution of data and avoid hot spots.